# python curses: detect text's display width before printing it

Tags: python, terminal, curses

I'm using Python and curses to make a little text editor.

However, I'm having some trouble when trying to compute the width of a given text.

In particular, I've noticed that Chinese characters (e.g. 大) and emojis (e.g. ) on my terminal (the default Terminal app on MacOS) actually take twice the width of a typical ASCII printable character.

Given a string I intend to display using curses, is there some way I can determine how many columns a string will use up on the screen without actually displaying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a window which you will not `refresh` (i.e., treating it as a *hidden* window), and obtain the y,x coordinates after printing into the hidden window.

It is unnecessary for the application to know how the curses library interprets the data (whether it uses `wcwidth` for example), but only necessary to be able to observe what curses would do with the information.

That approach is used in the `lynx` browser to decide if special treatment is needed for wrapping text (see [source code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/lynx-snapshots/blob/d84fd6821970236a99d0d38b1df98c74463cec02/src/LYCurses.c#L2249)).  Although that is written in C, the same idea can be used in the Python binding for curses.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `wcwidth()` and `wcswidth()`. They're not in the standard library (and not part of curses), but are available via `pip install wcwidth`.